# (Hackerrank) (Game of Stones) How could i find answer if unspecified condition

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/game-of-stones-1/problem

Game Of Stones.

Two players called `P1` and `P2` are playing a game with a starting number of stones. Player 1 always plays first, and the two players move in alternating turns. The game's rules are as follows:

In a single move, a player can remove either 2, 3, or 5 stones from the game board.
If a player is unable to make a move, that player loses the game.
Given the starting number of stones, find and print the name of the winner. `P1`  is named First and `P2` is named Second. Each player plays optimally, meaning they will not make a move that causes them to lose the game if a winning move exists.

For example, if `n = 4`, `P1` can make the following moves:

`P1` removes 2 stones leaving 2. `P2` will then remove 2 stones and win.
`P1` removes 3 stones leaving 1. `P2` cannot move and loses.
`P1` would make the second play and win the game.

**Function Description**

Complete the gameOfStones function in the editor below. It should return a string, either First or Second.

gameOfStones has the following parameter(s):

n: an integer that represents the starting number of stones

**Input Format**

The first line contains an integer , the number of test cases.
Each of the next  lines contains an integer , the number of stones in a test case.

**Constraints**

1<= n,t <= 100

**Output Format**

On a new line for each test case, print First if the first player is the winner. Otherwise print Second.

**My question**

In this Document from link, Players can take 2, 3 or 5 stones each turn.

But, if the number of stones and the number of conditions are different for each cases, how do i write the code?

For example. Case 1, players can take 2, 3 or 5 stones, and Case 2, players can take 2, 4, 7, 9 stones.

and Code will pass both case.

Input
Case 1:

```
3  //total conditions of stones can take
2 3 5 //player can take 2, 3 or 5 stones
8 // Number of cases of number of starting stones
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
10
```

Case 2:

```
4  //total conditions of stones can take
2 3 7 9 //players can take 2, 3,7 or 9 stones
5 // Number of cases of number of starting stones
5
6
7
10
15
```

And Code will pass both cases. How should I write the coding that satisfies this case?

Comment: You can use either a breadth-first search or a depth-first search to determine which player wins.  The actual number of stones taken during a turn can be put in an int array.

Comment: The game doesn't change.  They just want you to say who wins given different starting numbers of stones.  If a player is given 1, they've lost because they can't move.  If they're given 2, 3, or 5, they can remove all of the stones and win. If they're given 4, they can remove 3 and leave 1 so that the other player loses, so they win.  If they're given 6, they can remove 5 and win because they' ve left 1 for the other player.  If they're given 7, they can take 2, 3, or 5 leaving 5, 4, or 2.  Unfortunately, all 3 of those are winning positions for the other player, so they've lost.

Comment: @vacawama What i mean, if they give another conditions like 2, 4 and 6 or 3 ,5 , 8 and 9 . How could make code for different conditions. Each case has different conditions and code should pass all cases. I added some detail example in document.

Comment: [put all the information relevant to your question, in your question](/help/how-to-ask). Add links only _in addition_ to properly describing the problem you have. If that link becomes a 404 (and it will), this question becomes complete nonsense, which you will agree is the opposite of why Stackoverflow is such a useful resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my solution to your new problem in Swift.  If you're not familiar with it, hopefully it is similar enough to languages you use to be useful.

This is a solution to the general case.

```swift
// This is an internal function that also takes a dictionary of results so that
// it can remember solutions it has already found
func game(n: Int, conditions: [Int], result: inout [Int : String]) -> String {

    // Have we seen this answer before?  If so, just return it
    if let answer = result[n] {
        return answer
    }

    if n < conditions.min()! {
        // I can't move because the number of stones left is fewer than
        // I'm allowed to take
        result[n] = "Second" // to speed up the solution, remember this result
        return "Second"
    } else if conditions.contains(n) {
        // I can take all of the stones, so I win
        result[n] = "First"  // to speed up the solution, remember this result
        return "First"
    } else {
        // Try taking each of the stones I'm allowed to take, and see
        // if that causes my opponent to lose
        for take in conditions {
            let leave = n - take

            // If the number of stones I leave causes the opponent to lose, I win
            if leave > 0 && game(n: leave, conditions: conditions, result: &result) == "Second" {
                result[n] = "First" // to speed up the solution, remember this result
                return "First"
            }
        }
    }
    
    // No way for me to win, so I come in second.
    result[n] = "Second"  // to speed up the solution, remember this result
    return "Second"
}

// Generate a dictionary to store already generated answers, and call the
// internal recursive routine
func gameOfStones(n: Int, conditions: [Int]) -> String {
    var result = [Int : String]()
    
    return game(n: n, conditions: conditions, result: &result)
}

print(gameOfStones(n: 4, conditions: [2, 3, 5]))   // "First"
print(gameOfStones(n: 6, conditions: [3, 7, 13]))  // "Second"
```

Comment: I already pass this case. My question is an application of this problem, but there is no direct connection. My question is if change rule each case like 2,3 or 5 to 2,4,7 or other conditions. How can i write code to pass all cases. For example, Case 1, player can take 2,3 or 5 stones and start with 10 stones. but Case 2, player can take 2,4,7 stones and start with 15 stones.

Comment: Then in that case, your test function would receive an array of the number of stones the user could take at each step in addition to the target number. Your code would loop over this array to decide how many stones to take at each step. If you as a player are left 0 stones, you have lost. If you are left the number of stones in the conditions array, you have won. Otherwise, you would try taking the number of each of the conditions and calling yourself recursively to see if any of those cause your opponent to lose. If so, you win. If none of those cause your opponent to lose, you lose.

Comment: Or if you are left fewer stones than are in any of the conditions array you have lost. For example, if you can take 3, 5, or 7, then both 1 and 2 are losing states.